# How to send response in trunk with expressjs/nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

i have an use case where i need to perform multiple apis call. I would like to send response from those api as soon as i get them to the client but not ending it.

how would i do this with expressjs/nodejs?

Comment: It's not clear what you need can you explain more?

Comment: @Michelem so i perform a bunch of api calls. then combine, make it an array and send to client. however i dont want to wait for everything to finish but sending them as they arrive.

Comment: Of course you can't do that in a single request. You should do multiple API  requests.

Answer (score -1):

You can't send multiple responses to one request.

so you need to make all API calls and bundle them in a json and send it as response.

Use request and bluebird (promise.all) to do this.